# How to convert datetime format?

Tags: python, datetime, format-conversion

I have datetime in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` i.e `(2022-04-30T07:00:00+0000)` format and I want it to be converted into `%Y-%m-%d` i.e `2022-04-30` format in python. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I have tried `date = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%Y-%m-%d")` and 
`date = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%Y-%m-%d").date()`, but it's not working.

Comment: Your format string has to cover the whole date/time string.

Comment: @Klaus D. I only want the date (2022-04-30), so how can I get it, actually there is a condition in which I have to compare those dates but the format I have of one date is "%Y-%m-%d" and the format of another date I'm getting is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: ...or just split the string on `T` ?